# PHP - Verifying FTP connection - Detect FTP Timeout

Tags: php

One of my CLI scripts downloads files via FTP.

The script opens an FTP connection, logs in, downloads the necessary files, and sleeps. Every so often it checks for the files again. This script is expected to run for days on end, as a daemon.

I want to be able to re-use an open connection (so I don't have to re-connect every loop).

```
$ftpconn = false;
$ftplogin = false;

while(1){

sleep(25);
if(!$ftpconn){
    $ftpconn = ftp_connect(HOST);
}
if(!$ftplogin){
    $ftplogin = ftp_login($ftpconn, USER, PASS);
}

// Do FTP stuff here

}
```

My question is this. Do both `ftp_connect` and `ftp_login` timeout? And if so, will `$ftpconn` and `$ftplogin` change to FALSE when that happens?

Thanks.

Comment: sleeps for 25 seconds? I think is enough for you to check files so that your connection will stay alive. ..

Comment: @Mihai Iorga the sleep could be 10 seconds, could be 300 seconds. the script has to run for days with no restart. i want to make sure i dont get stuck with a closed connection that doesn't get reopened. but i also dont want to keep opening new connections when i dont have to.

Comment: let's assume the sleep is longer than the time the connection stays alive. or assume it got broken for whatever reason. how would i then know the connection needs to be reopened? i can't just assume it'll stay alive

Comment: Why can't you just have it initialize a connection when it needs it and terminate it when it is done? What is the advantage of leaving the connection up?

Comment: @Drahkar if the sleep is 5 seconds then my script will (assume there's nothing to download) just keep opening and closing FTP every 5 seconds and listing the files. why do that when it can just use the connection that's already open without closing/opening so often? Keep in mind this script runs as a daemon

Comment: i want to be able to detect when the connection timed out

Answer (score 1):

You're best bet on this is to implement your connection process. Then build your logic for trying to check for the file. (I'm assuming using something like ftp_nlist). ftp_nlist will return a FALSE if there is an error for any reason. At which point you can have your code close the existing connection using ftp_close (Which will give a FALSE if the connection was already closed for whatever reason) and then run the connection sequence again.

You'll want to build in logic that if the ftp_nlist fails more than a few times to exit out of your application. Unfortunately the various ftp_* commands don't have a lot of depth in regards to identifying why a function failed so you will have to build extra logic around it to compensate.

Comment: my ftp_nlist always checks the same directory. if it were to fail, it would either be loss of internet or a closed connection. so this is a method i have already considered. i was just wondering if there was any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I also have a compounding problem: for some reason, there's no way to distinguish between an actual error and an empty response (when the file list is empty). `ftp_nlist` returns FALSE in both cases (also noted [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php#122642)), and `ftp_rawlist` returns an empty array in both cases.

So my first hunch was to do a cheap call, like `ftp_pwd`, to see if the connection is still open. However, PHP does some caching apparently, so that won't work. However, you can force PHP to run the same call over the FTP connection with this:

```php
$result = ftp_raw($ftpConnection, 'pwd');
print_r($result);

// Array
// (
//     [0] => 257 "/www/html"
// )
```

This should *always* give a response (given a working FTP connection), which will be an array with a single item. If there's an error, it will be an empty array.